# How to add class into html tag manually by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress-theming

I want to add class "dropdown-toggle" into `<a href="#">Additional< /a>` this tag but as there is no class before that's why "str_replate" not working perfectly.

I want to add class for only this tag using php there are also `<a>` tag but I don't want to add the same class for all. I hope you understand. See my code:

```html
<li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-97">


    <a href="#">Additional</a> ***I want to add class for only this "<a>" tag not others tag***
**after adding the class the tag will be "< a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Additional< /a>"***


    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69">
            <a href="http://localhost/wp-web/simpleshop/checkout/">One</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68">
            <a href="http://localhost/wp-web/simpleshop/cart/">Two</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70">
            <a href="http://localhost/wp-web/simpleshop/my-account/">Three</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: When specifying small pieces of HTML in a Stack Overflow question, please use backticks, so they appear correctly: `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using javascript for adding class instead instead of php because it is more convenient and used in every type of extension files.

Here is the answer

```
<li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-97">

<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Additional</a> ***I want to add class for only this "<a>" tag not others tag***
**after adding the class the tag will be "< a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Additional< /a>"***

<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69">
        <a href="http://localhost/wp-web/simpleshop/checkout/">One</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68">
        <a href="http://localhost/wp-web/simpleshop/cart/">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70">
        <a href="http://localhost/wp-web/simpleshop/my-account/">Three</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<script>
   function myFunction() {        
     var element = 
       document.getElementById("myDIV");            
       element.classList.add("mystyle");
      
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. but can not add "onclick="myFunction()"" into the < a> tag. because "<a href="#">Additional</a>" it's default from WordPress. actually I am developing theme with wordpress and got this problem. Thank you again.

Comment: Okay, no worries